# Клик по Iframe, в не поля Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Можно ли реализовать такое? 
Iframe 500px на 500px, обернут в div который 1000px на 1000px. Я кликаю в любой части дива, но попадаю по айфрейм и тем самым его активирую. 
Возможно это смена координат клика, или другие методы, подойдет любой, мне просто нужно активировать айфрейм) Заранее спасибо Ребята!

```html
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px; border-color: #008a77; border-style: solid; padding: 5px">
    <iframe width="500px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pCKDrDvaOKE"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как то так, но я не уверен, что это будет запускать видео Ютуба. Если нужен именно запуск видео, то тоже можно сделать, но это уже отдельный вопрос.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0].onclick  = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(".block iframe")[0].click();
}
```

```css
.block{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-color: #008a77;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px
}
.block iframe{
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <iframe onclick="alert('Мы нажали на Iframe')" style="width:100px; height: 100px;" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Задача заключается именно в том что запустить видео, не нажимая на видео)

Comment: Ваш ответ хороший, но не подходит, от меня + всеровно)

Comment: Постараюсь чуть позже сделать чтобы запускалось видео...